# Java 8 Nested stream find minimum

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, java-stream

I have a data structure like this:

```
class Parent {
  List<Child> children;
}
class Child {
  DateTime date;
}

List<Parent> parents = ...
```

I want to find the earliest `Child` DateTime in all the `parents`

I want one result. The earliest `DateTime` across all the `parents` and all their `children`.

```
List<Parent> parents = create();

List<Child> epp = new ArrayList<Child>();//earliest per parent

parents.forEach(c -> c.getChildren()
                      .stream()
                      .min(Comparator.comparing(Child::getDate))
                      .ifPresent(d -> epp.add(d)));

Optional<Child> earliest = epp.stream()
                              .min(Comparator.comparing(Child::getDate));
```

Loop each parent, add the earliest per parent into the `epp` list, and then I loop the `epp` list to find the actual earliest.

Is this the most concise / best way to achieve with Java8?

Comment: Oracle discourage using `forEach` to add to `epp` like that (http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/moocjdk8/documents/week3/lesson-3-3.pdf).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes there is. You don't need to use the intermediate list if you flatten the map to children:

```
Optional<Child> earliest = parents.stream().
    .map(Parent::getChildren).flatMap(List::stream)
    .min(Comparator.comparing(Child::getDate));
```

If you are able to change the `Parent` class then you might want to add a `streamChildren` method in Parent:

```
class Parent {
    public Stream<Child> streamChildren() {
        return children.stream();
    }
}
```

This has the advantage of not giving the caller access to the underlying `List`.

As an aside, you didn't need to create your own `ArrayList` in the original solution. You could have used:

```
List<Child> earliest = parents.stream().map(Parent::getChildren)
    .map(children -> children.stream().min(Comparator(Child::getDate)))
    .filter(Optional::isPresent).map(Optional::get).distinct()
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

That avoids the side effect of the 'add' operation.

Comment: Yes sprinter, that works nicely. I want to mark this as the answer, but let's say Parent was an external API that I couldn't change, what would be theway to go without adding the 'streamChildren' method?

Comment: @kwh yup, roughly `flatMap(p -> p.getChildren().stream())` instead

Comment: Yep as zapl says. I'll add it to the answer for future reference. I just like the style of the method references and use them wherever possible.

Comment: `map(Parent::getChildren).flatMap(List::stream)`

Comment: In the latter code: `List<Child> earliest = parents.stream().map(Parent::getChildren).filter(ch -> !ch.isEmpty()).map(ch -> ch.stream().min(comparing(Child::getDate)).get()).distinct().collect(toList())` would be a little bit shorter. You don't need to stream empty list and check optionals afterwards.

Comment: @TagirValeev Agreed, though it's not so robust. Add a `filter` before the `min` at some later date and you risk a latent bug. Having said that I don't particularly like the `isPresent`, `get` idiom. Luckily java 9 will give us `Optional.stream` which is a more elegant solution.